# Comparing 2 .XLS files and outputting the result in a new .xls file?

Tags: c#

So i was writting a program to compare 2 .xls files and outputting the differences in a new .xls file. By differences I mean the difference in the values. Also there are multiple sheets in a .xls file. How can I achieve this in c#

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle Excel files is to start Excel and control it via the Office interoperability libraries. Reading and writing .XLS files yourself is very, very difficult, and remote-controlling Excel is not hard at all.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati is a tolerable starting point for what functions to call, what assemblies to use, and all like that.